# Can't open an image after compiling in cx_Freeze

Tags: python, image, pygame, cx-freeze

Basically after creating the executable, pygame suddenly can't open the `.png` images.

I am using Python 3.5 and cx_Freeze version 5.1.1.

The images are in the same directory than the game file. The game runs just fine before making it an executable. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name="Mygame",
      version="1.0",
      description="my game",
      options={"build.exe":{"packages":["pygame"],
                            "included_files":["vivi.png","anastasia.png","Bird.png"]}},
      executables=[Executable("george_abc.py")])
```

Here is the error that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Μάνος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
module.run()
File "C:\Users\Μάνος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "george_abc.py", line 164, in <module>
pygame.error: Couldn't open vivi.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are typos in the `options` dictionary: `build.exe` should be replaced by `build_exe` and `included_files` by `include_files`, see the `cx_Freeze` [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe).

```
options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"],
                      "include_files":["vivi.png","anastasia.png","Bird.png"]}},
```

Once you have made the executable, you should be able to see the image files `vivi.png`, ... in the build directory.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that